# How should I get my array into the rendering function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope, closures, jsx

I know there is a problem with scopes, but I don't know how to fix it.
I have two functions.
`mapSubject` is to get the data and rebuild it.
`subjectFilter` is to render sth with the data rebuilt.
So how can I make it work to put 'majorArray' as a param in `subjectFilter` ?

```
const subjectFilter = (arr) => {
    arr.map(sub => {
      return (
        <div>
          <label>{sub}</label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            placeholder={sub}
            className="subject"
          />
        </div>
      )
    })
  }
```

```
  const mapSubject = (data) => {
    const majorArray = []
    data.map(item => {
      if (item.major1 && !majorArray.includes(item.major1)) {
        majorArray.push(item.major1);
      }
      return majorArray
    })
    console.log(majorArray)
  };
```

```
return(
  <div>
    {subjectFilter()}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do as

```
const subjectFilter = (arr) => {
  return arr.map((sub) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>{sub}</label>
        <input type="checkbox" placeholder={sub} className="subject" />
      </div>
    );
  });
};

const mapSubject = (data) => {
  const majorArray = [];
  data.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.major1 && !majorArray.includes(item.major1)) {
      majorArray.push(item.major1);
    }
  });
  return majorArray
};

return <div>{subjectFilter(mapSubject())}</div>;
```